Two links not getting parsed correctly
As you can see in this comment of mine, the two links [1] and [2] are not getting parsed correctly. Yet the markdown code I used there is exactly the same I used here, i.e.:
[[1]](http://kaifangcidian.com/han/yue/%E5%89%A9) and [[2]](http://kaifangcidian.com/han/yue/%E5%87%80)

and yet here they are getting parsed. So what is going on in that comment? Is this a malfunction in the comment markdown? If so, it is a bug, otherwise I need support with the link markdown to stop this from happening again next time, which explains the two tags to this question.

Apparently it was a bug, but it has been fixed since.
It didn't work in your comments because they behave differently than posts. So I fixed them for you. This is how they should look:
[`[1]`](http://kaifangcidian.com/han/yue/%E5%89%A9) 

Add the back ticks so that it escapes the characters. 
